# Adding content to dynamic line breaks

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to emulate JSDoc visual design for some textual content. I would like to add ' * ' to each line.

Below I broke apart lines by adding each line to own paragraph.

HTML Structure:

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
  </p>
  <p class="text">
    consectetur adipisicing elit. 
  </p>
    <p class="text">
    Sunt dignissimos hic voluptatem
  </p>
  <p class="text">
    in fugit aperiam tempore. Odio 
  </p>
    <p class="text">
    debitis, numquam doloremque
  </p>
  <p class="text">
    laboriosam, commodi fugit 
  </p>
  <p class="text">
    possimus veritatis autem quos 
  </p>
  <p class="text">
    nesciunt, dignissimos facere.
  </p>
</div>
```

Styles:

```css
.container {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace;
}

.container:before {
  content: '/**';
  white-space: pre;
}

.container:after {
  content: ' */';
  white-space: pre;
}

.text:before {
  content: ' * ';
  white-space: pre;
}
```

But I would like to know if this can be achieved on dynamic line breaks/word wraps that adapt to parents width as in the following example:

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 
    elit. Sunt dignissimos hic voluptatem in fugit aperiam 
    tempore. Odio debitis, numquam doloremque laboriosam, 
    commodi fugit possimus veritatis autem quos nesciunt, 
    dignissimos facere.
  </p>
</div>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/kamenjan/pen/oVBqbr) for additional clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

I updated and used `em` units instead, for indent/padding and positioning of the pseudo, and with that it adjust automatically with the set font size. And as the pseudo inherits its parent font size, it match each text line too.

---

One can't dynamically inject a character like that when a line break, unless using a script. And even with, it would not be that easy, to recalculate where and when to insert the stars.

A simple trick, using CSS only, would be to position the pseudo element absolute, having enough *stars* to cover for the text, hide the overflow, and then, with a padding, indent the text.

*A note, I changed to CSS3 syntax for the pseudo, which prefix pseudo elements with 2 colons, so unless you need to support IE8, use the newer syntax.*

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
  width: 390px;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.container::before {
  content: '/**';
  white-space: pre;
}

.container::after {
  content: ' */';
  white-space: pre;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;        /* hide overflowed stars */
  padding-left: 1.5em;      /* indent text */
  margin: 0;               /* remove p's default top/bottom margin */
}

.text::before {             /* note: "\A" in "content" create line break */
  content: '*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A*\A';
  white-space: pre;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: .6em;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 
    elit. Sunt dignissimos hic voluptatem in fugit aperiam 
    tempore. Odio debitis, numquam doloremque laboriosam, 
    commodi fugit possimus veritatis autem quos nesciunt, 
    dignissimos facere.
  </p>
</div>
```

---

Another option, as commented by Temani Afif, would be to set a fixed width on the pseudo, which would avoid the need to have line breaks `\A` in `content`, end result becomes the same though.

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
  width: 390px;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.container::before {
  content: '/**';
  white-space: pre;
}

.container::after {
  content: ' */';
  white-space: pre;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;        /* hide overflowed stars */
  padding-left: 1.5em;      /* indent text */
  margin: 0;               /* remove p's default top/bottom margin */
}

.text::before {
  content: '*********************************************';
  word-break: break-all;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: .6em;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 
    elit. Sunt dignissimos hic voluptatem in fugit aperiam 
    tempore. Odio debitis, numquam doloremque laboriosam, 
    commodi fugit possimus veritatis autem quos nesciunt, 
    dignissimos facere.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: you can avoid setting all the line break `\A` by giving a fixed width to the absolue element that will create the wrap alone

Comment: @TemaniAfif True, thanks, added a sample, end result same :) ... and I updated with `em` units to keep indent/padding and pseudo position related to set font size

Answer (score 1):

In case you want a more dynamic way where the number of line is unknown, you can consider the `*` as a background image that you repeat. You can then have any number of lines and also change the font-size like you want

Here is an example where I will use this icon: https://fontawesome.com/icons/asterisk?style=solid (you can easily change with another one later)

```css
.container {
  width: 390px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  margin:5px;
}

.container::before {
  content: '/*';
  display:block;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.container::after {
  content: '*/';
  display:block;
  margin-left:12px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin: 0; 
  line-height:1.2em;
  background:url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"  ><path fill="currentColor" d="M478.21 334.093L336 256l142.21-78.093c11.795-6.477 15.961-21.384 9.232-33.037l-19.48-33.741c-6.728-11.653-21.72-15.499-33.227-8.523L296 186.718l3.475-162.204C299.763 11.061 288.937 0 275.48 0h-38.96c-13.456 0-24.283 11.061-23.994 24.514L216 186.718 77.265 102.607c-11.506-6.976-26.499-3.13-33.227 8.523l-19.48 33.741c-6.728 11.653-2.562 26.56 9.233 33.037L176 256 33.79 334.093c-11.795 6.477-15.961 21.384-9.232 33.037l19.48 33.741c6.728 11.653 21.721 15.499 33.227 8.523L216 325.282l-3.475 162.204C212.237 500.939 223.064 512 236.52 512h38.961c13.456 0 24.283-11.061 23.995-24.514L296 325.282l138.735 84.111c11.506 6.976 26.499 3.13 33.227-8.523l19.48-33.741c6.728-11.653 2.563-26.559-9.232-33.036z" class=""></path></svg>') 12px -2px/0.5em 1.16em repeat-y;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 
    elit. Sunt dignissimos hic voluptatem in fugit aperiam 
    tempore. Odio debitis, numquam doloremque laboriosam, 
    commodi fugit possimus veritatis autem quos nesciunt, 
    dignissimos facere.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 
    elit. Sunt dignissimos hic voluptatem in fugit aperiam
  </p>
</div>

<div class="container" style="font-size:12px;">
  <p class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 
    elit. Sunt dignissimos hic voluptatem in fugit aperiam
  </p>
</div>
<div class="container" style="font-size:24px;">
  <p class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 
    elit. Sunt dignissimos hic voluptatem in fugit aperiam
  </p>
</div>
```

You can also consider the same icon for the first and last `*`

```css
.container {
  width: 390px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: 'Lucida Console', Monaco, monospace;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  margin:5px;
}

.container::before,
.container::after{
  content: '/';
  width:2em;
  display:block;
  font-weight:bold;
  background:url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"  ><path fill="currentColor" d="M478.21 334.093L336 256l142.21-78.093c11.795-6.477 15.961-21.384 9.232-33.037l-19.48-33.741c-6.728-11.653-21.72-15.499-33.227-8.523L296 186.718l3.475-162.204C299.763 11.061 288.937 0 275.48 0h-38.96c-13.456 0-24.283 11.061-23.994 24.514L216 186.718 77.265 102.607c-11.506-6.976-26.499-3.13-33.227 8.523l-19.48 33.741c-6.728 11.653-2.562 26.56 9.233 33.037L176 256 33.79 334.093c-11.795 6.477-15.961 21.384-9.232 33.037l19.48 33.741c6.728 11.653 21.721 15.499 33.227 8.523L216 325.282l-3.475 162.204C212.237 500.939 223.064 512 236.52 512h38.961c13.456 0 24.283-11.061 23.995-24.514L296 325.282l138.735 84.111c11.506 6.976 26.499 3.13 33.227-8.523l19.48-33.741c6.728-11.653 2.563-26.559-9.232-33.036z" class=""></path></svg>') 12px -2px/0.5em 1.16em no-repeat;
}

.container::after {
  text-align:right;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin: 0; 
  line-height:1.2em;
  background:url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"  ><path fill="currentColor" d="M478.21 334.093L336 256l142.21-78.093c11.795-6.477 15.961-21.384 9.232-33.037l-19.48-33.741c-6.728-11.653-21.72-15.499-33.227-8.523L296 186.718l3.475-162.204C299.763 11.061 288.937 0 275.48 0h-38.96c-13.456 0-24.283 11.061-23.994 24.514L216 186.718 77.265 102.607c-11.506-6.976-26.499-3.13-33.227 8.523l-19.48 33.741c-6.728 11.653-2.562 26.56 9.233 33.037L176 256 33.79 334.093c-11.795 6.477-15.961 21.384-9.232 33.037l19.48 33.741c6.728 11.653 21.721 15.499 33.227 8.523L216 325.282l-3.475 162.204C212.237 500.939 223.064 512 236.52 512h38.961c13.456 0 24.283-11.061 23.995-24.514L296 325.282l138.735 84.111c11.506 6.976 26.499 3.13 33.227-8.523l19.48-33.741c6.728-11.653 2.563-26.559-9.232-33.036z" class=""></path></svg>') 12px -2px/0.5em 1.16em repeat-y;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 
    elit. Sunt dignissimos hic voluptatem in fugit aperiam 
    tempore. Odio debitis, numquam doloremque laboriosam, 
    commodi fugit possimus veritatis autem quos nesciunt, 
    dignissimos facere.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 
    elit. Sunt dignissimos hic voluptatem in fugit aperiam
  </p>
</div>

<div class="container" style="font-size:12px;">
  <p class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 
    elit. Sunt dignissimos hic voluptatem in fugit aperiam
  </p>
</div>
<div class="container" style="font-size:24px;">
  <p class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 
    elit. Sunt dignissimos hic voluptatem in fugit aperiam
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: If you take a closer look, you'll see the stars doesn't match the lines properly. E.g., change font size to 48px in your last sample and you'll see they move upwards for every line, mine doesn't as the pseudo pick up its parents font, hence will always work no matter font.

Comment: So it is debatable whether yours is _"a more dynamic way"_ ;) ... unless you can make the background image (svg) inherit the container's font size.

Comment: @LGSon the *more dynamic way* isn't the example I made, it's the use  a background that you repeat which will make it more easy to handle ... I simply picked the first one I found on the net and approximate the different values, then it's for OP (in case he want to use this) to perfectly adjust the different values and use his own background. As a side note, I wasn't comparing with your solution when saying *more dynamic*. He was asking for a dynamic way so I started my sentence with that word.

Comment: First off, you say _"In case ... where the number of line is unknown"_. Since the whole question is about exactly that, unknown number of lines, so saying _"In case..."_ feels completely wrong. Second, your posts normally is _good, working solutions_, this one actually isn't, as the stars move upwards, line by line, so what happened? Became answering more important than quality, or is it me who thinks wrong?